# SQL Server - only join if condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables (at least, something similar) with the following relationships:

Item table:

```
 ID      | Val
---------+---------
 1       | 12
 2       | 5
 3       | 22
```

Group table:

```
 ID      | Parent  | Range
---------+---------+---------
 1       | NULL    | [10-30]
 2       | 1       | [20-25]
 3       | NULL    | [0-15]
```

GroupToItem table:

```
 GroupID | ItemID
---------+---------
 1       | 1
 1       | 3
```

And now I want to add rows to the GroupToItem table for Groups 2 and 3, using the same query (since some other conditions not shown here are more complicated). I want to restrict the items through which I search if the new group has a parent, but to look through all items if there is not.

At the moment I am using an IF/ELSE on two statements that are almost exactly the same, but for the addition of another JOIN row when a parent exists. Is it possible to do a join to reduce the number of items to look at, only if a restriction is possible?

My two queries as they stand are given below:

```
DECLARE @GroupID INT = 2;...

INSERT INTO GroupToItem(GroupID, ItemID)
SELECT  g.ID,
        i.ID,
FROM    Group g
JOIN    Item i ON i.Val IN g.Range
JOIN    GroupToItem gti ON g.Parent = gti.GroupID AND i.ID = gti.ItemID
WHERE   g.ID = @GroupID
```

-

```
DECLARE @GroupID INT = 3;...

INSERT INTO GroupToItem(GroupID, ItemID)
SELECT  g.ID,
        i.ID,
FROM    Group g
JOIN    Item i ON i.Val IN g.Range
WHERE   g.ID = @GroupID
```

So essentially I only want to do the second JOIN if the given group has a parent. Is this possible in a single query? It is important that the number of items that are compared against the range is as small as possible, since for me this is an intensive operation.

EDIT: This seems to have solved it in this test setup, similar to what was suggested by Denis Valeev. I'll accept if I can get it to work with my live data. I've been having some weird issues - potentially more questions coming up.

```
SELECT  g.Id,
        i.Id
FROM    Group g
JOIN    Item i ON (i.Val > g.Start AND i.Val < g.End)
WHERE   g.Id = 2
AND     (
            (g.ParentId IS NULL)
            OR 
            (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM GroupToItem gti WHERE g.ParentId = gti.GroupId AND i.Id = gti.ItemId))
        )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65146/26)

Comment: See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Your queries are far from being syntactically correct.  Can you edit the queries to be closer to what you are actually using?  Or is the problem to fix the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO GroupToItem(GroupID, ItemID)
SELECT  g.ID,
        i.ID,
FROM    Group g
JOIN    Item i ON i.Val IN g.Range
WHERE   g.ID = @GroupID
and (g.ID in (3) or exists (select top 1 1 from GroupToItem gti where g.Parent = gti.GroupID AND i.ID = gti.ItemID))
```

Answer (score 0):

If a Range column is a varchar datatype, you can try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO GROUPTOITEM (GROUPID, ITEMID)
SELECT A.ID, B.ID
FROM GROUP AS A
LEFT JOIN ITEM AS B
ON B.VAL BETWEEN CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(A.RANGE,1,CHARINDEX('-',A.RANGE,1)-1),2,10) AS INT)
    AND CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(A.RANGE,CHARINDEX('-',A.RANGE,1)+1,10),']','') AS INT)
```